# How i can Keep user login session alive for fixed time in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I already tried to login with 50 concurrent users and visit a page, its working fine.

But its automatically logout after sometime.

How i can Keep user login session alive and sending request in defined time frequency in jmeter.

Possible duplicate : [Maintaining http request in jmeter for certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071157/maintaining-http-request-in-jmeter-for-certain-amount-of-time)

Comment: How much wait time do you have between requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For maintaining session: it depends on how it is implemented on application under test side. The most commonly used configuration is:

   - Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
   - Make sure that `Clear Cookies each Iteration` box is not ticked
2. For sending request in defined time frequency, use one of the following:

   - [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
   - [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) - this one more precise on < minute time spans, more flexible and easier to use but you'll have to install a plugin